# javascript method chaining and the this object

Tags: javascript

Given a chained function declared something like:

```
Something.prototype.method1.method2 = function(){
    return this === Something.prototype.method1; // true
}
```

How (if possible) can I get access to the calling instance object?

```
instance.method1.method2() // access to instance and method1?
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to misuse JS then ignore my answer.

Otherwise let me show what the idea chained functions is about. The prototype functions can be used after each other, because they return always the `this` pointer. so the next function in the chain will be called on the same object:

```
Animal = function Animal(name) {
  this.food = 0;
  this.name = name;

  return this;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function eat() {
  this.food--;

  return this; 
}

Animal.prototype.hunt = function hunt() {
  this.food++;

  return this;
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
// Lets create Jack the cat.
var cat = new Animal('Jack');

// Let him hunt and eat with some chained function calls.
cat.hunt().hunt().eat();

// Check how much food does Jack got.
console.log(cat.food) // => 1

// Some explanation about this return values.
var anotherPointerOnCat = cat.hunt();

console.log(anotherPointerOnCat === cat) // => true
// True because they point on the same object in memory.

// So I can call the chained functions on that as well.
anotherPointerOnCat.eat().eat();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define it during construction:

```
function Thing() {
  var _t = this;

  this.method1 = function() {
    console.log('method1', _t);
  }

  this.method1.method2 = function() {
    console.log('method1.method2', _t);
  }
}
```

Works in the Chrome console:

```
var t1 = new Thing();
t1.a = 1;
t1.method1();
t1.method1.method2();

var t2 = new Thing();
t2.b = 2;
t2.method1();
t2.method1.method2();
```

Yields:

```
method1 "Thing {method1: function, a: 1}"
method1.method2 "Thing {method1: function, a: 1}"
method1 "Thing {method1: function, b: 2}"
method1.method2 "Thing {method1: function, b: 2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Something.prototype.method1.method2 = function(){
    return this === Something.prototype.method1; // true
}
```

You claim that this function will always return true. But, this is not true. an example:

```
var jsIsFun = Something.prototype.method1.method2;
jsIsFun(); //false
jsIsFun.call(Something.prototype.method1); //true
```

This is because the `this` keyword is bound on function execution. Using the `call()` method we can however alter what is bound to `this`.

This happens because the Context of the function is applied on execution.

You however want to have access to variables not directly in your object/function.

We also have a word for this: Scope.

And the problem you have is not understanding Scope and how it works in JS.

Comment: What you're referring to is called Context. Scope if the visibility of variables in different blocks.

Comment: @PatrikOldsberg yup indeed. I kind of skipped a few sentences while typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the object up as a chain object, that is to set the object up such that it takes an argument that could be a parent, and have it return a different object, but with the same chain.

Stealing @burninggramma's example:

```
function buildChain(parent, method){
   var child = {};
   child.prototype = parent;
   child.parentage = function(){
     var chain = [];
     if (child.prototype.parentage) {
       chain = child.prototype.parentage();
     }
     chain.push({obj:this, method:method});
     return chain;
   }
}

function Animal(name){
  this.food = 0;
  this.name = name;

  return this;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function eat() {
  this.food--;

  return buildChain(this, this.eat); 
}

Animal.prototype.hunt = function hunt() {
  this.food++;

  return buildChain(this, this.hunt);
}
```

And to use:

```
var cat = new Animal('Tom');
var mouse = new Animal('Jerry');

cat.hunt().hunt().eat().parentage(); // [{obj: cat, method: hunt}, {obj: chain1, method: hunt}, {obj: chain2, method: eat}]
mouse.eat().eat().parentage(); // [{obj: mouse, method: eat}, {obj: chain1, method: eat}]

var chainer = cat.hunt().eat();
chainer.parentage(); // [{obj: cat, method: hunt}, {obj: chain1, method: eat}]
chainer.hunt().parentage(); // [{obj: cat, method: hunt}, {obj: chain1, method: eat}, {obj: chain2, method: hunt}]
chainer.eat().parentage(); // [{obj: cat, method: hunt}, {obj: chain1, method: eat}, {obj: chain2, method: eat}]
```